# Lightning component on administrator home page only

Tags: lightning-aura-components, home-page-component

I have a Lightning Component made for `Home` page.

Is it possible to put it on administrator's home page only ?

Answer (score 3):

yes you can set it to specific profiles as per you need.
From lightning app builder create a new home page and add the custom component from the component panel assign it specific profiles

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll need to create a new home page, then assign it to your admin profile.  Setup > Lightning App Builder > Home Page.

[image: Custom Homepage]

Add the lightning component you made - along with any others - to the lightning home page:

[image: Add components]

Then save, "Activate", and assign the new homepage to your desired profiles. Since I'm new on this community, I am unable to post more than 2 screenshots, so I'll follow up with them in another response.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 additional screenshots previously mentioned:

[image: Save Lightning home page]

[image: Assign Lightning home page]